# Invalid HMR message error Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm getting the following error from Webpack:

`Invalid HMR message` Followed by a string of very detailed JSON.

There really aren't any resources that I can find to better debug this. Any tips?

[image: Webpack console errors]

Bonus if anyone can give me insight to why `require` can't be found when it's used throughout the app no problem.

**Here are some details:**

- Running Node/Babel
- Using Webpack

NPM dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
    "cuid": "^1.3.8",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^2.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
```

Webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

  var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',

  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client',
          './index.js',
  ],
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.+\.config.js/],
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react-hmre'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        CLIENT: JSON.stringify(true)
      }
    })
  ],

  externals: nodeModules

};
```

Comment: Can you post your webpack config? Can you also post a simple component where you are seeing this issue?

Comment: added that @Anuj see above.

Comment: Why `target: 'node'` ?

Comment: because "The target: 'node' option tells webpack not to touch any built-in modules like fs or path." @BobSponge

Comment: Setting the environment variable CLIENT should be able to use true as is without the need for JSON.stringify.

Comment: You'll need to post module.js because the error about require is on line 10.

Comment: `module.js` doesn't exist in my project @RobBrander

Comment: It is generated.  You can access it by clicking on the right side of the error message where it says 'module.js:10'.

Comment: Also, you can see it by accessing the console in chrome, under the Sources section, there is a webpack:// that you can click on and explore to find module.js

Comment: Can you show me the loading order of your JavaScripts in your `script` tags?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. If you're referring to the base HTML file that references the bundle, it's one tag.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `target` from `node` to `web` for the client.js.

If you are bundling a server side React app, you can add to the top of server file:

```
require('css-modules-require-hook')({
  generateScopedName: '[name]--[local]',
  prepend: []
});
```

So that the css-files required in SSR react components work.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set target to 'web' because your intention is to compile for the web.

You should set the engine to node (which is what I'm assuming you were trying to do using target).

```
target: "web",
engines: {
  node: "4.x"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this doesn't seem to resolve the hmr issue

Comment: making target: "web" will only remove the error - require not defined. I am also dealing with the same problem. I actually think it has something to do with webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr statement in entry of webpack.config.js. I am just not able to figure what is the role of this